# quantmod adds indicators twice to chart

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod

When plotting a chart with quantmod's chartSeries() called from Shiny server, the technical indicators are added twice to the chart.

If the below code is executed from the console the results is as expected. When executed by the Shiny App server the RSI and MACD are added twice to the chart. Although the print statement only shows once.

```
getChart.raPortfolio <- function(obj) {
  if(is.xts(obj$chart)) {
    print("Was here!")
    chart <- chartSeries(obj$chart, 
      name = obj$symbol,
      theme = chartTheme("white"),
      type = "line", TA=c(
        addBBands(n = 50),
        addMACD(fast = 12, slow = 26, signal = 9),
        addRSI(n=14)
      )
    )
  }
  return(chart)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the assign to chart object prior to return, which only caused an issue when called via Shiny (not when run on the console). Below behaves correctly, including when adding indicators.

```
getChart.raPortfolio <- function(obj) {
  chartSeries(obj$data, 
    name = obj$symbol,
    theme = chartTheme("white")
)}
```